# Adding square brackets in json after split and convert from CSV in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a scenario where I have to split a csv in certain number of rows, and for each batch there should be json file generated through PowerShell Script.

Here is what I am doing as of now:

```
$csv = "C:\Desktop\report.csv"

[int]$totalRows = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $csv
while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null) { $totalRows++ }
$reader.Dispose()

$totalRows
$startRow = 0
$counter = 1

while($startRow -lt $totalRows)
{   
    Import-CSV $csv | Select-Object @{expression = { "Append this value"+ $_.Name}; label = 'NewName'}, @{expression = {$_.Account}; label = 'AccountNumber'} | Select-Object -skip $startRow -first 2 | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "C:\Desktop\r_$($counter).json"
    
    $startRow += 2
    $counter++
}
```

The only problem here is that I am not able to enclose the Account number values in square bracket []:

Actual : `"AccountNumber":  "123"`
expected : `"AccountNumber":  ["123"]`

Also I am not sure on how to put whole json in each file under a root element through this. Also not sure if this "ConvertTo-Json" is the way to go as csv data needs to be edited, Please help.

Here is a csv for reference-

```
Name,Account,Role
John,123,Second
Rocky,345,Third
Tony,234,First
Rocky,345,Second
Matt,999,Second
Bernard,888,Third
Matt,999,First
Jacob,789,Second
Angela,777,Second
Jacob,789,First
```

Expected Output

First File:

```
{   
    "details":
    [
        {
            "NewName":  "Append this valueJohn",
            "AccountNumber":  ["123","333"]
        },
        {
            "NewName":  "Append this valueRocky",
            "AccountNumber":  ["345"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Second File:

```
{   
    "details":
    [
        {
            "NewName":  "Append this valueTony",
            "AccountNumber":  ["234"]
        },
        {
            "NewName":  "Append this valueRocky",
            "AccountNumber":  ["345"]
        }
    ]
}
```

So on till 6th file:

```
{   
    "details":
    [
        {
            "NewName":  "Append this valueAngela",
            "AccountNumber":  ["777"]
        },
        {
            "NewName":  "Append this valueJacob",
            "AccountNumber":  ["789"]
        }
    ]
}

Thanks
```

Comment: Why do you need it in square brackets? it is not an array

Comment: Change `expression = {$_.Account}` to `expression = {'[{0}]' -f $_.Account)}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This is writing the output in slight different way than expected: "[123]", I am trying to get it as ["123"], I guess it should be converted to array somehow.

Comment: @AmitChouksey Are you perhaps mistaking CSV for JSON? `[]` for lists/arrays is not a common practice in CSV generation

Comment: `$Csv | Select-Object @{expression = { "Append this value"+ $_.Name}; label = 'NewName'}, @{expression = { ,@([String]$_.Account) }; label = 'AccountNumber'} | Select-Object -skip $startRow -first 2 | ConvertTo-Json -Compress`?

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand "lists/arrays is not a common practice in CSV generation". @iRon: this is throwing this: "AccountNumber":  {
                              "value":  [
                                            "123,333"
                                        ],
                              "Count":  1
                          }
Which is very different.

Comment: Please add the expected output (of `C:\Desktop\r_$($counter).json`) to the question. Btw, it might look different, but the from a [`json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) point of view it is still valid and the contents is in fact the same as when you omit the `-Compress` parameter where the lines (including the square brackets) are placed on different lines).

Comment: expected output: 
{
 "details":
 [
  {
   "NewName":  "Append this valueJohn",
   "AccountNumber":  ["123","333"] #for more than one values 
  },
  {
   "NewName":  "Append this valueRocky",
   "AccountNumber":  ["345"] #for single values
  }
 ]
}

Comment: So, why are you using `Json` ([ConvertTo-Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json))? Square brackets have a special meaning in [`Json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (quote: "*Arrays use square bracket notation...*") and therefore automatically escaped with: `\[` when converted from an object. If you expect `"AccountNumber":  ["123"]`, why not simply: `|Select-Object @{expression = { "Append this value"+ $_.Name}; label = 'NewName'}, @{expression = { """AccountNumber"": [""$($_.Account)""]"}; label = 'AccountNumber'}`? Why the `Json`?

Comment: @iRon its just that I will have to ask the other team who is expecting this input, I am not sure if [] can be omitted, but last I asked they were keen on this. And I am very new to PowerShell, I still dont understand the expressions, I am trying to understand what our comment meant and explore more but no luck :( Edit: Just wanted to add, if you look my whole requirement it is to break csv into batches and then convert to json. The code I am using is doing that but I doubt if its a good idea to use convertTo-Json

Comment: Also note that you can't just append to `Json` like `ConvertTo-Json |Add-Content -Append` for the same reason. It will invalidate your `Json` as arrays (multiple items) need to be surrounded by square brackets. It is still not clear what you expect a `Json` file or a `csv` file (I guess a `Json` file but that will not shown from a single property/value). Please add the whole expected contents (of a single iteration) to the question. I think you will need to investigate in what `Json` is to be able to satisfy "the other team" with a correct file.

Comment: just added expected output iteration wise

Comment: Ok, it is clear now that you expecting an `Json` file but the logic behind the contents is still unclear to fully answer the question: why are there two values (`["123","333"]`) for `John`? Why are there just two accounts in a file? Anyways, as commented earlier: use the [Array subexpression operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) to force an array which will surround the value in brackets in your json result. See also: [Add square brackets while convert it to json in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52584436/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments as I can't use newlines in there:

Converting the below PowerShell object to [**`Json` (JavaScript Object Notation)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

```
@{
    details = @{
        NewName = 'Append this valueJohn'
        AccountNumber = 123
    }, @{
        NewName = 'Append this valueRocky'
        AccountNumber = 345
    }
} |ConvertTo-Json
```

Results in

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "NewName": "Append this valueJohn",
      "AccountNumber": 123
    },
    {
      "NewName": "Append this valueRocky",
      "AccountNumber": 345
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to quote the values, you will need to force them to a string
(by using quotes or e.g. the `[String]` initializer):

```
@{
    details = @{
        NewName = 'Append this valueJohn'
        AccountNumber = "123"
    }, @{
        NewName = 'Append this valueRocky'
        AccountNumber = [String]345
    }
} |ConvertTo-Json
```

Results:

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "NewName": "Append this valueJohn",
      "AccountNumber": "123"
    },
    {
      "NewName": "Append this valueRocky",
      "AccountNumber": "345"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you also want to put the *single item* (scalar) strings between square brackets (which represents an array), you will need to force the values to an array using the [Array subexpression operator `@( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) or the [Comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comma-operator-). Note that this automatically happens when it concerns multiple values, e.g.: `AccountNumber = "123", "333"`

```
@{
    details = @{
        NewName = 'Append this valueJohn'
        AccountNumber = @("123")
    }, @{
        NewName = 'Append this valueRocky'
        AccountNumber = ,[String]345
    }
} |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

<sup>[(Also note the `-Depth` parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583678/1701026)</sup>
Results:

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "NewName": "Append this valueJohn",
      "AccountNumber": [
        "123"
      ]
    },
    {
      "NewName": "Append this valueRocky",
      "AccountNumber": [
        "345"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the square brackets aren't on the same line as per default the [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) expands the output. You might consider to use the `-Compress` parameters but that will put *everything* on the same line:

```
{"details":[{"NewName":"Append this valueJohn","AccountNumber":["123"]},{"NewName":"Append this valueRocky","AccountNumber":["345"]}]}
```

In other words, even the appearance is different, it all technically equal and represents the same object.

Comment: So I have finally used the preparing a custom json approach, and it worked, though I am not convinced that it is the best way but here is a summary:

first : $accountNumber = @($line.Account) -replace ',', '","'
then in script
$jsonData = @"
{
 ....
 $AccountNumber = ["$accountNumber"]
}
there were other edits too such as seperating the nested json with comma, but I was able to use replace and regex to get it done.